# SetError on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an android app. I am having an `EditText` on which I have applied `OnCllickListener()`.

```
 EditText _input = new EditText(context);
_input.setSingleLine(true);
_input.setFocusable(false);
```

I am setting `OnClickListener()` on this `EditText`:

```
_input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // OnClick work here
            }
        });
```

I have applied some validations on this field and calling `setError()` method on this `EditText`. It shows that red icon of error in the `EditText`when the validation fails. But when I click on that error icon it executes the `OnClickListener()` on this `EditText`and I am not able to see the error occurred.

Is there any other way to do so, so that I can handle both functions.

Thanks a lot in advanced !!!

Comment: You can setError with both the icon and error text like so:
`mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));` and then there's no need to specifically click on the red icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an error like like this:

```
if(view.getError() == null) return;
```

See the doc here

> getError()
>   Returns the error message that was set to be displayed with
>   setError(CharSequence), or null if no error was set or if it the error
>   was cleared by the widget after user input.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getError())

Comment: I have implemented the above but I am still not able to see the error. Is there any way using which I can display the error.

Answer (score 0):

You would check if currently the edit text is in an error state, within the onclick handler:

```
_input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view.getError() == null) {
                    // do not handle the click
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with a simple solution. Just set text of editText to empty string before setting error and error message will show again like without onClickListener.